# Updating mysql table with values from another only when different

Tags: mysql, sql-update, distinct

I have a table called `obj` which has multiple columns including one called `id` and one called `desig`. I need to update this column with the values of the `id` column in another table called `orb`, wherever the first table's `desig` value equals the second table's `desig` value. However, I only want it to run the update when the `id` value coming in from the `orb` table is different from the already existing `id` value in my `obj` table.

This is what I have:

```
"UPDATE obj INNER JOIN orb ON (obj.desig = orb.desig) SET obj.id = orb.id
WHERE obj.id IS DISTINCT FROM orb.id;"
```

Unfortunately I can't actually test it myself because I don't have the permissions to update this table, so I need some second opinions. Will this do what I need it to do?

Edit:

```
orb table:                   obj table:
desig | id | size         desig | id | name
1912A | 372| 20           1912A | 431| j8
1912B | 192| 17           1912B | 192| sh7
```

After updating the obj table, I'd like it to look like:

```
desig | id | name
1912A | 372| j8
1912B | 192| sh7
```

So it gets the `id` from the orb table where the `desig`s are the same. But to save time, I only want it to run the update if `obj.id != orb.id` to start with.

I was also thinking this command might work (I want to use the one that's fastest):

```
"UPDATE obj, orb SET obj.id = orb.id WHERE obj.desig = orb.desig AND
obj.id != orb.id;"
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result set ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Please see new edit

Comment: your query looks fine to me